# Is it possible to call local functions from imported in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vuex, vuex-modules

I have simple file called `_mixin.js` which consists of:

```
const mutations = {
    _set(state, data) {       
        for (let key in data) {
            if (key in state) {
                state[key] = data[key];
            }
        }
    },

    _reset(state) {
        const s = initialState();

        Object.keys(s).forEach(key => {
            state[key] = s[key];
        });
    }
};

export default {
    mutations
};
```

What I'm trying to do is share this two methods between all existing modules mutation like this:

```
import _MIXINS from 'store/modules/_mixins';

function initialState() {
    return {
        id: null,
        email: null,
        password: null,
        name: null,
    };
}

const state = initialState();


const mutations = {
    ..._MIXINS.mutations,

    setId(state, id) {
        state.id = id;
    }
};
```

The problem is that browser says it cant find function `initialState` as its not in same file.

Comment: You need to import the function to the other module, but it is perfectly possible to import and use local functions in vuex.

Comment: @Eggon can you provide example ?

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this:

// sharedLogic.js

```
export function initialState () {
    // your logic
}
```

// store module

```
import { initialState } from '<pathTo sharedLogic.js>'
const state = initialState();
```

// mixin module

```
import { initialState } from '<pathTo sharedLogic.js>'
const mutations = {
   ...
    _reset(state) {
        const s = initialState();

        Object.keys(s).forEach(key => {
            state[key] = s[key];
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: The problem is that `initialState` is uniq in each file and mixin if one for all files

Comment: I'm sorry, but in this case I do not understand your question anymore. You wrote that `initialState` can not be found (and it can't because its not defined in `_mixin.js`). So i thought you want to use the same function in both modules. But now you wrote that you want different ones? So where's the definition of the other one?